# result of count query in room database doubles the actual records in a table

Tags: android-room

This is my first question for seeking a solution to a problem. I have solved various problems from here. Thanks for these useful solutions, tips and tricks from you. I'm developing app where I need to count records from two tables. I'm using room and kotlin in android studio. I have tried following **count query** but the **result is quite 'DOUBLE' of actual records** that was being added.
the query in DAO interface is as follows..

```
@Query("SELECT tSubject.regular, tSubject.code, Count(tNote.id) AS countFeSe 
FROM tSubject LEFT JOIN tNote ON tSubject.code = tNote.sub 
WHERE tNote.std=:std AND tNote.div=:div AND tNote.sem=:sem 
GROUP BY tNote.sub 
ORDER BY tSubject.code ASC")
fun noteCountByStd(std: Byte, div: Byte, sem:Byte):List<SubAndCount>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that the above was correct except one minor error in it. And finally solved the problem by changing GROUP BY **tNote.sub** field as follows. Now it is working as expected. You may be notice other minor changes of using DISTINCT and OUTER. Removing of those words didn't change my result.

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT tSubject.regular, tSubject.code,
Count(tNote.id) AS countFeSe
FROM tSubject LEFT OUTER JOIN tNote 
ON tSubject.code = tNote.sub 
WHERE tNote.std=:std AND tNote.div=:div AND tNote.sem=:sem
GROUP BY tSubject.id ORDER BY tSubject.code ASC")
fun noteCountByStd(std: Byte, div: Byte, sem:Byte):List<SubAndCount>
```